# I have tested an APK with Admob in Firebase Test Lab and many clicks have been done in the ads

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebase-test-lab

So I have accidentally uploaded to Testl lab (Robo test) an apk (.aab) that was uploaded a few months ago to PlayStore and has admob working in it with real ads. I have seen in the video that the robo test has done like 20 clicks in an ad and I am afraid my admob account could be banned.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @TylerV I just want to know if it is okay and I won't have to worry about that..

Comment: See: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/295004)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to worry. Admob ignores clicks that come from test lab. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/get-started#mobile-advertising